# Convert webp to jpeg using JS

Tags: javascript, converters, webp

We have a React application with nginx.

I need to replace all images to the webp format. But safari does not support webp, so the question is: is it possible on the user side, without SSR, convert images from webp to jpg, using only JS?

Comment: On a browser not supporting WebP? Not efficiently. Normally this is done with `<picture>`; is there a reason you can’t use it?

Comment: @Ry- we do not want to store two versions of the same image in the database

Comment: The question is why you really need webp. It's not well supported as you know, so I don't think displaying it for public is a great idea now, unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Theoretically, not practical at all, you can use canvas to convert webp to jpg on the fly. But how heavy it is for the client..

Comment: @V.Volkov if the browser doesn't support displaying .webp, it most certainly won't allow drawing it on canvas.

Comment: I think your question is underspecified. What does it mean "I need to replace"? Why? You need to store both or just display them? If it's just for displaying, convert them and store JPG.

Comment: @RoboRobok Reasonable :) Worth testing :)

Comment: @RoboRobok only webp is stored in the database. if the user agent is a safari user, I run the converter and replace all the pictures src

Comment: Can't you convert all images to widely supported format and use these new images everywhere?

Comment: @RoboRobok jpeg is used everywhere now, but we want to make both the page for the user and the database faster. safari users constitute a smaller part of the users of our site, so what we want to do is convert only them

Comment: How does webp make your website faster?

Comment: @RoboRobok WebP offers 25 – 35% smaller file sizes at the exact same SSIM quality index

Comment: It only makes real difference when you display lots of images at once. If you're sure you need that, you won't avoid storing the JPG versions server-side or using some server-side image converter.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to use `<picture>` tag to advice both formats to a browser to pick by itself and load the supported one. No JS is needed in your case.

Comment: You can also deliver webp format on the server side. But this solution fails, if you decide to use Cloudflare